# Trouble understanding laravel eloquent models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

It's been a some time since I've programmed with Laravel and I'm stumped by the relations I need in order to create a foreign key -link with 2 models.

I have a database where there's a table "company" containing companies, and I also have a table called "projects", which contains projects.

So the Projects- table contains a column called "employercompany" with a foreign key constraint to the company-table.

I'm trying to print out the company's name in a project page in laravel with

```
{{$project->employercompany->name}}
```

But keep getting "**Trying to get property of non-object**"

My model pages look like this:

//Company

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
   public function projects()
   {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Projects', 'employercompany', 'id');
   }
}
```

and

// Projects

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Projects extends Model
{
    public function employercompany()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }
}
```

I know this is an easy problem but I just can't wrap my head around it

*****EDIT*****

I found the solution. Thanks Radical for providing some insight.

I ended up changing the employercompany column to company_id and, all the others as such too.

After that I fiddled around what I'm guessing fixed the thing was that I changed my database search query from

```
DB::table('projects')->get();
```

into

```
Project::all();
```

Don't know if that was the change needed but it sure feels like it was.

Comment: In response to your edit: This change from `DB` to `Project::` is indeed needed. In your original case, you were doing a query purely on the table, so Laravel did not know to tie it to the `Project` model (Your result would have been just a collection of standard PHP object). By querying `Project::all()`, Laravel knows to interpret the results as `Project` model objects, and thus also brings in the relevant relations.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. That's what I figured it was doing. :) Been using Symfony alot lately, so didn't think this was such a big difference. Thanks for the explanation though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining a `belongsTo` relation like you have done, Laravel will try and 'guess' the keys you are using based on the class name. In this case, it will look for a column `company_id` on your `Projects` model since your model is called `Company`.

Like you have done for the `projects()` method on your `Company` model, you should tell Laravel that you are using the `employercompany` column to reference the `Company` model:

```
public function employercompany()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'employercompany');
}
```

For more information, see the relevant documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse).

In addition, to make things easier, it might be worthwhile to try - if possible - to adhere to what Laravel 'expects' your database columns to be called, so situations like this are resolved automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like

```
$project = Project::find($id); //id of project

$compnany_name = ($project->employercompany()->get())->name;
```